Practicing Dharma when we live in post-modern, apocalyptic Capitalism
This may be an unusual question but I'm wondering if any monk or scholar has written work or made lectures about the spiritual obstacles of Capitalism. Namely the atomization, alienation, crippling entertainments, omnipresent advertising, the uncertainty of holding jobs and fluctuating markets, the need to wage wars to reduce the overall wealth of the society and obtain resources.
We are not living in the time of Shakyamuni, Padmasambhava or Athisha. This is a spiritually confused, decadent world. Our spiritual obstacles are more complicated and strange than the obstacles of previous times.
Any ideas? Sadhu.

We can only conform to the Path, particularly maintaining the moral precepts.
Livelihood is often the most difficult part; having a livelihood that does not conflict with the moral precepts.
Apart from this, the practise of the higher Path does not change, which includes contemplation of impermanence, contemplation of death, recognition of not-self (life is only aggregates & elements); so to develop disenchantment & dispassion. In AN 10.60, it is said enlightenment is having a distaste for all of the world.
If we believe in 'rebirth', this means again adherence to the moral precepts.

Do you believe there are no new challenges to practicing the Dharma in postmodern capitalism vs Indian antiquity?

Yes, for laypeople, it is much more difficult. But as i said, for me, this relates to earning a living, obtaining housing. etc. But, certainly, there is also not the society at large helping a person to maintain the precepts. Instead, it is an individual that must rely much more upon themselves.

You know, one of the things I've learned is that noise does not disturb our quietness. Our quietness is disturbed when we attach meaning to noise. One can meditate through a hurricane if one dismisses the howling wind and raging downpour as 'mere' noises, attaching no meaning of threat or risk or consequences to them. Not that I recommend that as an exercise, mind you, but…
The nature of capitalism is that it is emphatically and progressively noisy. Capitalism is a system in which people feel they must demand attention, command loyalty, compel conformity, create competition, enforce difference and conflict to generate selling-points, obscure questionable activities behind litanies of deflection… Capitalism wants noise, and speed, and constant movement, because these trigger the thinking mind into spastic reactivity, and spastic reactivity is easy to manipulate in the direction of a product. And in capitalism one must sell the self the way one would sell a product, with glowing, overweening protestations of virtue and superiority, and nasty condemnations of competitors. Capitalism is a system in which certain juvenile characteristics — stubbornness, impulsiveness, self-involvement, a tantrum-prone self-righteousness, even a certain vindictiveness - are adaptive, and thus are retained by some well into adulthood. I think the proper buddhist term for this is: 'Blech'.
But it's all just noise, and we only give it the meanings we choose to give it. Our modern world isn't anything new or more complicated; it's just louder, faster, and more insistent. And the way to cope with that is by being clearer and more discriminative. Choose what meanings you hear and let the rest be noise.
I know this may sound unhelpful, because it doesn't address the idea that the world is going to hell in a hand-basket. But, you know… the world is always going to hell in a hand-basket in one way or another, and always has been. That's the nature of the delusion. The only way to fix it is to start pulling the basket apart, strand by strand by strand.

Well from my understanding it is quite literally impossible to attain nibanna as a householder. I am no scholar so am not versed and well read in the entirety of the Buddhas teachings (or latter sects) but from what I have been told/read, even in the Buddhas time there was only 1 person who attained nibanna who was NOT ordained. That person himself was a naked ascetic.
As you could imagine, and I guess already know from your question. These obstacles that we must constantly juggle as a householder. Job, money, debt and all sorts of obligations are massive obstacles to liberation, and even just practising the dharma. Example, i am convinced it is impossible to attain the higher levels of jhana as a householder. Buddha himself gave 10 condusive enviroments that are necessary for attaining jhanna and they themselves are all related to being in complete solitude away from other people and distractions. Job, money, bills etc are completely opposite of what is needed to attain jhanna.
Some (mahayana) sects of Buddhism exclaim that anyone can "become a Buddha in the here and now" though in any circumstance, among other such trivial platitudes. I find these claims both dubious and opposite of the Buddhas teachings.
Simple fact is that to attain liberation one needs to essentially do as the Buddha did. Sure we don't need to go to the extreme of asceticisms that Buddha did in folly while finding the path on his own. Hence why he taught the middle way after he attained liberation. Though what we genuinely do need is the 3 higher trainings, sila is often difficult while living in society, we often "have to" lie just to function in a society, but specifically concentration and by proxy, wisdom...these cannot truly be grasped until one wholeheartedly abandons samsaric endevours and put full effort into practice.
The obvious issue here lies in that finding the correct external conditions to practice correctly is an issue in of itself.
An irony because despite that the conditions require nothing. i.e you dont need to own anything or have responsibilities. The conditions are often hard to find.
An example from my country, UK. If I went into the woods to be in solitude, it is only a matter of time until someone finds me and tells me I have to leave, as literally everywhere on the entire planet minus international waters and Antartica, is "owned" by someone. Eventually that someone, or someone acting on their behalf (police for example) will tell you that you cannot sit and meditate because you are on someone else's land (despite in reality nobody can actually own land, just society is made up in fiction as such)
Then there is another conundrum that most sangha groups are somehow related to some colloquial cultural aspects that one may not want to abide in. One may not have the desire or be able to take ordination or the groups may not allow a lay person to camp and live on the grounds.
I explain all this just to put the point across that we do indeed live in a degenerate time (kali yuga) more degenerate that when the Buddha was here. We just have to try our best and scrape through the best we can. Even if that means staying as a householder and just practising sila and meditation the best we can.
Ultimately one only needs to experience nibanna once to become a sotapanna, and once you do that, liberation is assured, in this life or a future life. The issue there though, well once you experience that first glimpse of the goal, you will be unable to function in society correctly anymore and in most cases will become a pariah to your peers. Just because you could no longer relate to/with putajhannas and their swirl of emotions.
